# SSRS How to Divide row results by outside group row summary

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, divide

I feel like this should be easy but I can't figure it out.

[image]

[Result View]

[image]

This is logically what I think should work:

```
=(ReportItems("CustCounts2").value/ReportItems("RowTotal2").value)
```

But the RowTotal2 is an outside group and won't render.

Comment: Can you share your row and column groups (below the main design window). Also extend the screen shot of the main design so we can see where you row groups are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using a matrix, so this is based on what I think your data looks like..

I used this to generate some sample data

I created a dataset `DataSet1` with the following as the dataset's query

```
DECLARE @t table(office varchar(10), EstimateStatus varchar(10), Counts int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Office A', 'Loss', 92),
('Office A', 'Win', 971),
('Office B', 'Loss', 50),
('Office B', 'Win', 500)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then added a matrix, added office as the row group and EstimateStatus as the column group and finally counts as the data. I then added totals for both row and column groups.

Finally I removed the last column which was generated (as this was a total percentage column, that you did not have in your design).

I renamed the rowgroup for clarity to `GrpOffice` as you can see

The design looks like this

[image]

In the percentage column at the office level I used the following expression

```
=SUM(Fields!Counts.Value)/SUM(Fields!Counts.Value, "GrpOffice")
```

This reads get the sum of the Counts for this row (even if there is only 1) and divide it by the sum of the counts this the whole group `"GrpOffice"`. Note this name must be in quotes and is case sensitive.

For the total row I used a similar expression..

```
=Sum(Fields!Counts.Value) / Sum(Fields!Counts.Value, "DataSet1")
```

This reads, get the sum of counts in the current scope (total column group in this case) and divide by the sum of the counts for the entire dataset called `"DataSet1"`

With a format of `p2` on those cells to tidy it up, we get the following output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I would have never assumed you needed to incorporate the actual Row Groups Name.

Comment: No problem. This is well worth reading, once you understand scopes, life is a little easier. You don't waste time trying things that will never work and often find shortcut to problems that seem much more difficult. It's a bit wordy but about half way down the page are examples that explain things.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-scope-for-totals-aggregates-and-built-in-collections?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I do a lot of SSRS reports, so this is very helpful. Thanks again Alan.

Answer (score 0):

It has something with .Data file size. As it exceeds certain limit error starts appearing. Deleting that file will force the project to recreate the .data file and issue will disappear temporarily.